# Understanding the genotype written in terms of two genes

Tags: genetics, human-genetics

I have some doubt in understanding the following genotypes: HCV-Tg/AID(+/+), HCV-Tg/AID(-/-) and HCV-Tg/AID(+/-), where HCV-Tg stands for "Hepatitis C Virus (HCV) core proteins" and AID for the gene "Activation-induced cytidine deaminase". So it is about two different genes. It is clear though what is meant by for example AID(+/+) in terms of ist alleles, but in the case I am talking about these are two different genes. In the case HCV-Tg/AID(+/-) it could for example mean that one allele is mutated at each of the two genes, but it could also mean that in the first gene (HCV-Tg) one allele is WT and in the second gene (AID) one allele is mutated. And lastly it could also mean that in the first gene both alleles are WT and in the second gene both alleles are mutated.

Can somebody help me understand what is exactly meant ?

Many thanks.